# Does my employer have access to my information after I leave a job?

Tags: job-change, quitting, job-security

I am just wondering: if I ever left my job, will my previous employer still have access to my personal information, like my Social Security Number, etc.? Is this for a limited period or forever?

Comment: Please include your location. As I recall, EU countries have laws relevant to this.

Comment: VTC - Legal / HR specific question.  There are most likely laws in your country that govern how the HR company in question should deal with your personal data after your no longer employed with said company.

Comment: @MisterPositive I agree that there are legal aspects, but if the location is identified, any HR professional in that country should know the answer to that question.

Comment: @DavidK I agree with you in this instance.   Its not always clear where the LEGAL line is to be drawn.  VTC retracted.

Comment: @MisterPositive [This Meta discussion](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1856/what-is-asking-for-legal-advice) helped me better understand the distinction.

Comment: @DavidK I feel a whole lot better about my original thought of VTC based on the fact that it is ON Hold, and considering the Elders who put it ON Hold.

Comment: @MisterPositive Agreed, though once this gets a country definition I'll probably nominate for reopen.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on your location and the company. Most places I know have a requirement to keep records for set amounts of time. And all that I know of have no requirement to destroy records about former staff.

Most businesses would archive it until the archive burnt down I would think. It's company information.

Answer (score 5):

## Ask your HR department

Sorry, but it's that simple.  There's no reason at all why you can't ask your own company how your data is used during and after your employment.

Most decent sized companies have this kind of regulatory information listed in their intranet (sometimes called "Staff Handbook").  You could try there if you don't want to ask personally.

Failing that, look up the corporate data protection laws for your country.

Answer (score 1):

In most countries, a company will be legally required to keep information about you for a certain time (usually six years). The reason is that there might be disputes for some time after you leave. For example, the tax office might claim that your taxes were not paid properly, and then the company should be able to respond to that. Or there is a problem that your company paid into a pension fund and for whatever reason the money is not there.

And good companies will have your name and contact details and a note "Hire again" or "Don't hire again" - if you left the company on good terms, and in three years time they need a similar employee, they might just call you to see if you are willing to come back.